# permanent damage from SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I want to execute some SELECT statements to get some data out of an application database (production environment, not test), can I cause any **permanent** damage?

I've heard its not recommended to use SELECT * because it slows things down etc. but I assume there is nothing that could be affected in the long run? Can it somehow impair the application performance for the users of the application for more then possibly a few seconds?

Comment: a SELECT can slow the system, and certain types of complex queries can cause data to be cached in TempDB, and as a result of that TempDB can grow.  Although a SELECT cannot generally damage the system, it can still create a performance imbalance, it depends on how critical the DB system is and what you are going to do.   SELECT * wouldn't create an automatic degradation, it's more of a bad practice best avoided in production work, using to take a quick look at a record is no big deal

Comment: another thing that can go wrong is records getting locked in edit mode, well supposedly I'm told by some other developers, I've not seen it though.

Comment: but that slowdown and the performance imbalance you write about is temporary right? So only really complex SELECT queries which make TempDB grow can permanently slow things down?

Comment: You needn't nothing complex to eat sever resources. Just CROSS JOIN of a pair of rather big tables for example.

Comment: SELLECT * may include irrelevant colums, which means data transfer can take some extra time. That's it! Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Regarding permanent damage, always ask for lowest permission when you're accessing production database. `SELECT` itself will not cause damage to data, but nobody can guarantee that you really ONLY execute select statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really cause *permanent* damage.  A run-away query could prevent other people from accessing the database, because it ties up resources.  It could also fill up temporary space, shared among all users.

But, you would have to have quite complicated queries to accomplish such things.  Merely putting `select *` is an otherwise well-performing query will not cause such problems.

You should consider two things.  First, understand execution plans so you can get an idea of how the database really works and how each query will be executed.  Second, ask for a smaller database with sample data so you can play around and have less chance of interfering with others.